# How to display the Phaser Game Screen only in a Route React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, phaser-framework

I want that my game screen only been displayed in '/game' route, but when I give the boot with method "new Phaser.Game(config)" he start shows in every route '/home', default rote '/', '/error', '/game' and etc.

`game.js`

```
import Phaser from 'phaser';
import LoadScene from './scenes/LoadScene.js';
import MenuScene from './scenes/MenuScene.js';

export const config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  scene: [ MenuScene, LoadScene]
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

`gamepage.js`

```
import config from '../../phaser/game.js';
import React from 'react';

export default class GamePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <>
            <Game />
        </>;
    }
}
```

`routes.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import ErrorPage from '../pages/error/index.js';
import Home from '../pages/home/index.js';
import GamePage from '../pages/game/index.js';

export default class Rotas extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <>
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/game" elememnt={<GamePage />} />
                    <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </>
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `config` object in `new Phaser.Game(config);` accepts a `parent` option, which specifies the element that will contain the game canvas. If it is `undefined` then it will be included in the document body (***your case***).

You can specify `null` so that it is not included anywhere, and you are responsible for adding it to the DOM.

See https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig#GameConfig for the available options.

You can also have a look at [How to integrate Phaser into React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667188/how-to-integrate-phaser-into-react) as they use that approach

Comment: Thanks and an addition, I had to add my config game variable to the Class GamePage, there my config it can find the parent path and I wrote "elememnt" instead "element" on my Routes file.